# Vectorised `signal.lfilter`

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to apply `lfilter` on a collection of 1D arrays, i.e. on a 2D array which its rows correspond to different signals. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from scipy import stats

sysdim=2 #dimension of filter, i.e. the amount that it depends on the past
ksim=100 #number of different singals to be filtered
x_size=10000
# A and C are 
A=np.random.randn(sysdim*ksim).reshape((ksim,sysdim))
B=np.random.randn(sysdim*ksim).reshape((ksim,sysdim))
C=2.0*np.random.randn(sysdim*ksim).reshape((ksim,sysdim))
D=2.0*np.random.randn(sysdim*ksim).reshape((ksim,sysdim))
print A.shape,np.random.randn(x_size*ksim).reshape((ksim,x_size)).shape
x=signal.lfilter(A,np.hstack((np.ones((ksim,1)),C)),np.random.randn(x_size*ksim).reshape((ksim,x_size)),axis=1)
y=signal.lfilter(B,np.hstack((np.ones((ksim,1)),D)),x,axis=1)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Can somebody guide me please?

Answer (score 1):

So, you get the error on the line `x=...`

The shapes of your parameters are numerator: (100,2), denominator: (100,3) and data: (100,10000). The problem you are having is that lfilter expects to use the same filter for all items it processes, i.e. it only accepts 1-d vectors for the nominator and denominator.

It seems that you really need to turn that into a loop along the rows. Something like this:

```
# denom_array: R different denominators in an array with R rows
# numer_array: R different numerators in an array with R rows
# data: R data vectors in an array with R rows
# out_sig: output signal
out_sig = array([ scipy.signal.lfilter(denom_array[n], numer_array[n], data[n]) for n in range(data.shape[0])] )
```

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html for more information on what lifter expects.

(But don't worry, the performance hit is minimal, most time is spent filtering anyway.)

Comment: thank you. I already wrote it with a for loop myself. Then why it gets a axis argument? And I also believe there should be some way to avoid the loop.

Comment: The axis argument is for the common situation where you want to apply the same FIR/IIR to a number of different signals. But as you seem to want to use different filter coefficients, you need to use the loop (at least AFAIK there is no function to do what you want). Why would you like to avoid the loop? The code is often easier to read with it, and there should be no performance hit.

Comment: Since I have around 1K signals I believe a loop is actually limiting the speed.

Comment: Profile, do not believe :) If your signals are longer than a few samples, most of the time will be spent in lfilter. You may want to notice that a lot of the code in numpy is in python, so doing things by yourself is not necessarily much faster. (Don't optimise before you know where the bottleneck really is.) If your profiling shows that the loop is the culprit, then we'll have to take another look.

Comment: Thank you for letting me about Profile. I can use it but I don't know how can I compare it to the vectorised case. 

I am novice to python but usually vectorising the code speeds up the things enormously.

Comment: There are several ways to profile code in python. My favourite with numpy is to use the `ipython` console and its %prun magic. Interpreting the results is not that difficult. Your general idea of vectorizing is of course a good one, but python is surprisingly fast as-is, and with maths inner loops matter, outer loops not so much. Over-vectorizing with numpy leads to complicated code, as well. So, do not optimize unless you have a reason to do so.